# Visual Studio 2010 Command Line with Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, frameworks, command-prompt

Before, I was using VS 2008 command prompt and when I do

```
clrver
```

I got

```
Versions installed on the machine:
v1.1.4322
v2.0.50727
```

Now with Visual Studio 2010 command prompt I get :

```
Versions installed on the machine:
v1.1.4322
v2.0.50727
v4.0.30319
```

I want to know if there is a way to compile my C# code with the VS 2010 command line using the Framework 2.0 and not 4.0

-- Edit --

Is there another way than going in the properties of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MSBuild command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) and pass the `ToolsVersion` (2.0,3.0,3.5,4.0) and `TargetFrameworkVersion` (v2.0,v3.0,v3.5,v4.0) properties:

```
msbuild your.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0;ToolsVersion=3.5
```

The UI option is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the targeted framework in your project settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

(I do not yet have VS 2010 on my work machine, so I can't test whether or not support extends to .NET 2.0, though I believe it does)

Comment: It does go to 2.0 ... But is there a way that changes it so I could change between 2.0 and 4.0 without going in the properties?